# Boost-asio listening to multiple IP Addresses on a single (TCP) acceptor

Tags: c++, tcp, network-programming, boost-asio

A boost TCP acceptor can be wired up by using an endpoint constructor that only takes a port number as it's argument, in which case it will listen to all IP addresses/NIC's.

Is it possible to get the acceptor to listen to select IP addresses ? Or will I have to create an acceptor for each IP address I am interested in ?  Looking through the documentation I couldn't find any indications of this being a possibility.

I haven't looked at the socket API for a few years, but I guess the API doesn't directly allow this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there's unbound listening and bound one. unbound means you listen to all NICs, bound - to specific one. There's no possibility to select some of NICs, I think because the same can be achived by dedicated acceptors for each of them